# Assuming matrices $A,B,C \;\text{and}\;D\;$ are $ n\times n,$ show two ways that $(A+B)(C+D)=AC+AD+BC+BD$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

My way first of showing this is by letting $A,B,C \;\text{and}\;D\;$ equal
\begin{bmatrix}     
   a_{ij}
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   b_{ij}
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   c_{ij}
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   d_{ij}
   \end{bmatrix}

Respectively. I then used the distributive laws to show that both side are equal, but I cannot think of  another way.

Comment: multiply $[a_{ij}+b_{ij}]$ and $[c_{ij}+d_{ij}]$ ?

Comment: That's a good point, but is that not the same doing it if they were both singular as I did e.g. ([a]+[b])([c]+[d]) ? If not, then I guess that answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the distributive property of matrices to show this the second way.

Observe that $(A+B)$ and $(C+D)$ are each themselves $n\times n$ matrices. Using right distribution, $(A+B)(C+D) = (A+B)C + (A+B)D$. Then distributing to the left of each term, we obtain the desired result.